# Writing a custom JsonConverter to Deserialise JSON from POST on ASP.NET Core 2 controller

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, metadata, asp.net-core-2.0

I need to write a custom JsonConverter in my ASP.NET MVC Core 2 project to Deserialise JSON data within the body of a jQuery POST as it's default model binding. The difficult part here is I need TypeNameHandling on the object coming in which contains an array of the base type of an array of polymorphic types. I could annotate the object with

```
[JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)]
```

but the security concerns surrounding this is not acceptable for my project. I've written a custom JSON converter and marked my object instead with the below but it doesn't seem to use my custom converter (breakpoint is not hit).

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ApplicationLoggingConverter))]
```

Full relevant code below. My ApplicationLoggingModel:

```
public class ApplicationLoggingModel
{
    public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(ApplicationLoggingConverter))]
    public ModelActionBase[] Changes { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost("Save/{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Save(Guid id, [FromBody]ApplicationLoggingModel model)
    {
        model.ApplicationId = id;
        //nothing yet implemented
        return Ok();
    }
```

Custom Converter:

```
public class ApplicationLoggingConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly Type[] _types;

    public ApplicationLoggingConverter(params Type[] types)
    {
        _types = types;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize<ApplicationLoggingModel[]>(reader);
        }
        else
        {
            var myObject = serializer.Deserialize<ApplicationLoggingModel>(reader);
            return new ApplicationLoggingModel[] { myObject };
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return _types.Any(t => t == objectType);
    }
}
```

On Startup:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => { options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ApplicationLoggingConverter()); });
```

...and the JSON data I'm trying to post:

```
"$type": "Project.Web.Areas.Admin.Models.ApplicationLoggingModel, Project.Web",
"Changes": [{
    "$type": "Project.Generation.Common.Actions.EntityAction, Project.Services.Generation.Common",
    "Action": 0,
    "ItemName": "Entity",
    "PropertyName": "Name",
    "OldValue": "",
    "NewValue": "newEntity",
    "Scope": {

    }
}]
```

I'm pretty new to custom Deserialisation on ASP Core 2 modelbinding and the documentation on it is pretty scarce (unless I'm Googling/researching the wrong thing) but it seems like my breakpoint within "public override object ReadJson" should at least be hit. I've changed project names within JSON for security reasons and when I set TypeNameHandling.Auto it works, what am I doing wrong? Let me know if you need any more info/code.

Comment: `TypeNameHandling.Auto` on a *specific, typed property* is safe as long as you are willing to write your own whitelisting [`ISerializationBinder`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ISerializationBinder.htm) such as the `KnownTypesBinder` from the [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm).   Would you be willing to do that?

Comment: I had a look at that but it looks like it's more for serialisation/deserialisation within the code, I couldn't find any examples of how to use this on model binding. Would I be able to design my own and add it to startup and use it in that way?